# Visual studio 2017: Prevent css errors to be treated like "errors"

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with Visual studio 2017 with asp.net core (2.1). Some of my css files contains some problem.

[image]

Those problems are preventing me to run the server side.

How to prevent the VS treat those warnings as errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Options. Then under Text Editor > CSS > Advanced, you can set "Show errors as warnings" to true. You can also choose to turn off various bits of validation. There may also be a CssLint item there (can't remember if that's from one of my extensions or not). If so, you can choose to turn that off, if you like.

That said, CSS errors don't effect builds. They just show as errors to grab your attention, but you can easily publish with CSS errors. Not sure what exact problem you're having there.